# How to remove dashed line from HTML context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mobile-safari

To draw a dashed line in a canvas context, I use this

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');        
    ctx.setLineDash([5]);
```

When I don't want to draw more dashed lines I do this.

```
    ctx.setLineDash([0]);
```

Removing the dashs works in desktop browsers, but **this is not working in mobile Safari**. Is there another way to remove the dashes and draw plain continious solid lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wrap your code inside `context.save` / `context.restore`

```
ctx.save();
ctx.setLineDash([5]);
// draw dashed stuff
ctx.restore();

// now the default solid line is restored
```

Comment: It may work, but it's not always pratical to wrap it in more complex algorithms. So would indeed choose @Denis-kreshikhin answer.

Comment: @PauloBueno. I agree. At the time of my answer I didn't know that `[]` would clear the dashes -- or maybe that option was not available in the year before Denis's answer. Anyway, If there is no design reason to .save/.restore the canvas state I would now use `[]` to clear the dashes. Thanks for the heads up. :-)

Answer (score 59):

You can pass empty array. It also makes line solid.

```
ctx.setLineDash([])
```

```js
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.setLineDash([5, 3]);
ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 150, 100);


button.onclick = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(15, 15, 200, 200);
  ctx.setLineDash([]);
  ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button id='button'>Unset Dashed Line</button><br>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer. Saving and restoring context is expensive and a waste in the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain as simple as I can:

[image]